# GetOpt - 2. parameter of ArgDescr?

Tags: haskell, console

Module `System.Console.GetOpt`:
[Algebraic data type `ArgDescr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-Console-GetOpt.html#t:ArgDescr):
What are the 2. parameters of the constructors `ReqArg` and `OptArg` with type `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `String` parameters are used to represent the arguments in error messages and `usageInfo`. E.g. if you load the example `Opts1` module from [the Haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-Console-GetOpt.html#g:3), which contains lines like

```
    , Option ['L']     ["libdir"]  (ReqArg LibDir "DIR") "library directory"
```

and then test with the `compilerOpts` function from that module, while leaving out the mandatory argument of the `-L` option, you get an error message with usage info:

```
*Opts1> compilerOpts ["-L"]
*** Exception: user error (option `-L' requires an argument DIR
Usage: ic [OPTION...] files...
  -v        --verbose        chatty output on stderr
  -V, -?    --version        show version number
  -o[FILE]  --output[=FILE]  output FILE
  -c[FILE]                   input FILE
  -L DIR    --libdir=DIR     library directory
)
```

where the `DIR` mentions are straight from that second `ReqArg` argument for the `L` option, and similarly for most of the `FILE` mentions for the other options.